# Red Channel always on in RGBW Boost Circuit

Tags: boost, led-driver

I've designed and built a circuit ultilizing the Silergy SY7203 ([datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1804162155_Silergy-Corp-SY7203DBC_C125894.pdf)) CC boost IC to power 4 RGBW LEDs from a 2 cell Lion battery (~7.4v) with PWM control.
With or without being connected to a PWM signal, the red LED is always on. I thought the 10K resistor to ground would have handled this condition, but doesn't. I even switched to a 1K resistor with no luck.
Even though the datasheet has a few of the pins as NC, I connected them to ground because their suggested layout indicated they did as well.
I'm driving these LEDs at 500mA (.2/.4 = 500mA).
What am I missing?

[image: circuit]
[image: RGBW LED Specs]

Comment: How many red LEDs do you have in series? This is a boost converter without a switch for full shutoff, which means it will always output a minimum of the input voltage; if that's enough to turn on your LEDs, the LEDs will always be on.

Comment: There are 4 RGBW LED chips in series. That's a good point that I didn't consider. That seems to be the culrprit. Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Use a lower voltage battery, or use a converter topology capable of a true off state.

Comment: Do you have four separate channels, one for red, one for green and so on?

Comment: Yes - each color has a separate PWM signal. Which makes a supply side pmos tricky?

Comment: Also, you haven't linked the datasheet for your LEDs. When you use images (or anything else) taken from somewhere else on the internet, you are *required* by stackexchange rules to link to that source. Not only that, but it would be very helpful for understanding what's going on here (most RGB LEDs are common-cathode or common-anode, which would make it impossible to put multiple in series, so what are you doing?)

Comment: The datasheet was shared in private, as such, I am not willing to share publically outside arbitrary charts. This RGBW is neither a common anode or cathod. Each color has its own anode and cathode.

Comment: put a couple regular diodes in series to invisibly drop the voltage from the chip/supply to below the combined visual vf of the red LEDs. that smaller vf of a non-led will let you tweak the voltage, a Schottky can fine tune it further.

Comment: Please edit your question and add that. Your red LED has lower Vf than your input voltage which with no output disconnect on your boost converter will lead to them on all the time and if you don't have external resistors in series, uncontrolled current. Add one more in series or change to a boost converter to buck-boost for the red channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the red LED is always on

The IC is a boost converter with internal switch and control block:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9aX3k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From the datasheet, as you can see, when EN is low the converter is off. When it's off, the internal switch is off (i.e. no switching) therefore the circuit completes through the battery, boost choke (L1), diode (D1), LED and current sense resistor (R2). That's why your LED is always on. The current is set by the sense resistor (0R4) and the DC resistance of the choke.

Comment: Other than adding a 5th LED to ensure total voltage is below the minimum for the red channel, is there a minimal circuit to block the battery voltage? Perhaps a mostfet as a switch?

Comment: @Sean well, you can put a switch (e.g. PMOS) on the positive supply rail to the IC input and enable it with an external signal such as master enable (This should be separate from your PWM input).

Comment: While I could add a GPIO for that, I'd like to stick to the pinouts. I'm leaning towards switching to a buck/boost IC like MPQ2483 which handles such conditions.

Comment: @Sean Be aware that the MPQ2483 is an inverting buck-boost when used as a buck-boost converter. The output voltage will be negative.

Comment: I added 6 LEDS (5 wouldn't have been enough oddly enough) to bump the red forward voltage high enough to stay off when PWM isn't present. Works great now - thanks everyone!